# В чем может быть проблема при работе с библиотекой rembg в Python?

Tags: python

На просторах ютуба https://goo.su/wRLa нашел такой Python код:

```
from rembg import remove
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path


def remove_bg():
    list_of_extensions = ['*.png', '*.jpg']
    all_files = []

    for ext in list_of_extensions:
        all_files.extend(Path('input_imgs').glob(ext))

    for index, item in enumerate(all_files):
        input_path = Path(item)
        file_name = input_path.stem

        output_path = f'output_imgs/{file_name}_output.png'

        input_img = Image.open(input_path)
        output_img = remove(input_img)
        output_img.save(output_path)

        print(f'Completed: {index + 1}/{len(all_files)}')


def main():
    remove_bg()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Прога убирает фон у изображения из папки input  и помещает новое в папку output.
Если я запускаю его через процессор - запуская "pip install rembg" - все идет отлично.
Однако если я запускаю через gpu - "pip install rembg[gpu]", то сыпятся ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PY\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\PY\main.py", line 28, in main
    remove_bg()
  File "C:\PY\main.py", line 21, in remove_bg
    output_img = remove(input_img)
  File "C:\PY\venv\lib\site-packages\rembg\bg.py", line 133, in remove
    session = new_session("u2net")
  File "C:\PY\venv\lib\site-packages\rembg\session_factory.py", line 60, in new_session
    ort.InferenceSession(
  File "C:\PY\venv\lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\capi\onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._create_inference_session(providers, provider_options, disabled_optimizers)
  File "C:\PY\venv\lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\capi\onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 395, in _create_inference_session
    sess.initialize_session(providers, provider_options, disabled_optimizers)
RuntimeError: D:\a\_work\1\s\onnxruntime\core\session\provider_bridge_ort.cc:1029 onnxruntime::ProviderLibrary::Get [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : LoadLibrary failed with error 126 "" when trying to load "C:\PY\venv\lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\capi\onnxruntime_providers_tensorrt.dll"
```

Причем в последней строке идет ссылка на диск D, которого у меня даже нет.
Порывшись в гугле понял, что проблема в onnx среде - не представляю что это такое, но хотел бы разобраться. Вроде сама библиотека должна подтягивать данные и все должно вставать где нужно, но что то идет не так.
Может здесь есть просвященные, работающие с данной библиотекой и знающие в чем проблема.
Запускал в разных директориях; в версиях python 3.8, 3.10; Windows 10 ultimate

Answer (score 0):

при первом запуске происходит доп. подгрузка библиотеки с гугл диска. при большой загруженности программно соединение не устанавливается.
можно попробовать позже или скачать по ссылке(она есть в логах) и дальше думать, как подкинуть это библиотеке
В моем случае, следуя логам, проследил путь запросов: после неудачной попытки скачивания rembg пытался найти файл по адресу С:/user/.u2net/u2net.onnx
в папке С:/user/.u2net файла не было.
Скачал его по ссылке в логах и подкинул в папку.
Ошибка ушла.

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1tCU5MM1LhRgGou5OpmpjBQbSrYIUoYab
ссылка из лога, у меня была такая, но может быть и иная - судя по коду библиотеки

Comment: не, это я уже проверял, не помогло